# tensorflow tf.nn.conv2d convolve image with filters

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I have a grayscale image of size `(10000, 10000)` and `20` different filters of size `(150, 150)`. I would like to convolve an image with each filter using `tf.nn.conv2d`. Is there an elegant way of doing so without loops? A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923062/tensorflow-compute-tf-nn-conv2d).

I would like to have my output as a tensor of size `(10000, 10000, 20)`. The spatial dimensions are fine to be different, based on padding or strides. How to construct the input and filter shape for doing so? According to the same link, why is the following not an option:

Image: `(1, 10000, 10000, 1)`

Filter:`(150, 150, 1, 20)`

`tf.nn.conv2d(image, filter, [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME")`

In other words, why is a loop mandatory?